# Styling in HTML table

Tags: html, css

I want to apply the following style on my specific `td` but I dont know why its unable to do so

```
/*Style*/
font: 100%/1.4 "Alvi Nastaleeq", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: black;

<td colspan="2" class="centerAlign border">ABC</td>
```

kindly help to do so. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
   The class `centerAlign border` is class for all other `td`'s but I want to apply special styling on this cell.

Comment: Hi it's runnning check to this link http://jsfiddle.net/mWRMS/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a new style created for your td element

```
<style type="text/css">

.style1
{
font-size:100%;
font-family: "Alvi Nastaleeq", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #00000;
}
</style>
```

To use it just modify your td as such

```
<td colspan="2" class="centerAlign border style1">ABC</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use 100%/1.4 for your font-size. Anyway, wrap your style in another class and apply it to your element:

```
 .font-style {
      font-family: "Alvi Nastaleeq", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;         
      color: black;
      font-size: 13px;
 }
```

HTML:

```
 <td colspan="2" class="centerAlign border font-style">ABC</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Css**

```
.centerAlign.border{
font: 100%/1.4 "Alvi Nastaleeq", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>


<td colspan="2" class="centerAlign border">ABC</td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/mWRMS/1/

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
<td colspan="2" class="font">ABC</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Css

```
.font{

font-family:"Alvi Nastaleeq", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
color: #000000;
font-size:13px;
}
```